# linker issues: qmake and grantlee

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu

Has anybody experience compiling/linking with Grantlee on Ubuntu?
libgrantlee-dev is installed and auto-completion in QtCreator works fine, however I do not manage to get the example to build:

```
#include <grantlee_core.h>
#include <grantlee_templates.h>
#include <grantlee/engine.h>
#include <grantlee/template.h>
#include <grantlee/context.h>
#include <grantlee/variable.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Grantlee::Engine *engine = new Grantlee::Engine( 0 );
    Grantlee::Template t = engine->newTemplate("My name is {{ name }}.", "my_template_name");
    QVariantHash mapping;
    mapping.insert("name", "Grainne");
    Grantlee::Context c(mapping);
    t->render(&c); // Returns "My name is Grainne."
    mapping.insert("name", "Henry");
    c = Grantlee::Context(mapping);
    qDebug() << t->render(&c); // Returns "My name is Henry."
```

`qmake && make` results in:

```
undefined reference to `Grantlee::Engine::Engine(QObject*)'
```

and many other undefined-reference-errors, as I've missed some includes.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you link `libgrantlee-dev` with your Qt project?

Comment: I found no way to link libgrantlee-dev with qmake. However, building with cmake works like expected. find_package(Grantlee5 REQUIRED) does the trick. However it would be nice to know if there is something similar for qmake.

Comment: Do you write in `.pro` that this libraryry should be linked and path to this library (if it is not in the standard system library folder)? For example `LIBS += -Lpath_to_library_folder` and `LIBS += lgrantlee-dev` to link.

Comment: the path was missing. thank you!